# uiwebview not loading request even with delegate = self

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have created a NSObject class and included , in the init i create a uiwebview set the delegate to self and send the load request.

For some reason webViewDidFinishLoad or didFailLoadWithError never get fired. I can't figure why.

```
//
//  RXBTest.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface RXBTest : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>
@end
```

---

```
//  RXBTest.m
//  pageTest
#import "RXBTest.h"
@implementation RXBTest
- (id) init
{
     if((self=[super init])){
         UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
         [webView setDelegate:self];

         [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];
     }
     return self;
}   
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
     NSLog(@"ERROR LOADING WEBPAGE: %@", error);
}
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
     NSLog(@"finished");
}
@end
```

anybody has any ideas?

thanks
rudi

Comment: are you using `ARC` or `MRC`?

Comment: I'm using ARC and ios6 min.

Comment: that is the problem then. the local `UIWebView` will be deallocated immediately when you run out of the scope because nothing keeps the object alive... but it was also mentioned with the obvious solution by someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using ARC, then the problem is that your `webView` variable is local to the `init` method and therefore is getting deallocated before the web view finishes loading. Try adding the web view as an instance variable:

```
@interface RXBTest : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    UIWebView* webView;
}
@end

@implementation RXBTest
- (id) init
{
    if((self=[super init])){
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
        [webView setDelegate:self];

        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"ERROR LOADING WEBPAGE: %@", error);
}
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSLog(@"finished");
}
@end
```

If you are not using ARC, you will need to remember to release your `webView` object in the dealloc method as well.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to add this in your header file (.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIWebView.h>
```

Comment: Use the method: `- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` and put an `NSLog()` in there and see if it gets logged, if so, than it means the webView *does* load.