# How to load URL in Uiwebview with GameCenter data as parameters?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uistoryboard, game-center

I have a browser `webgame` ported to iOS using `UIWebView` (storyboard, not xib). The app is already published and works relatively well. My challenge now is to implement `GameCenter` properly so I can get the local player's playerID and then have a trustable unique id of the user. That's the only feature I really need from `GameCenter`.

The `GameCenter` functionality is actually implemented and working well, but for a reason I still couldn't understand I can't make the setAuthenticateHandler, located in a different class file, to access the `UIebView` so I can load an URL passing the playerId (among other parameters) via POST.

The `WebViewController.m` has a method who loads an URL in the `UIWebView`. The `setAuthenticateHandler` do call this method, but the `UIWebView` is null and of course it's not possible to load the URL. If I call the method inside `WebViewController.m` the URL is loaded correctly.

I was using ARC and then changed to MRC according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613361/3063226, but the behavior didn't change, the `UIWebView` is still null when `GameCenter` `setAuthenticateHandler` calls the `Load_URL` method.

Any help is very welcome. I have tried and researched a LOT for days before coming here to ask a question, I'm stuck!

**GCHelper.m**

```
- (void)authenticateLocalUser {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");

if (![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {

    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] setAuthenticateHandler:(^(UIViewController* viewcontroller, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Player logged in GameCenter!");

            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat: @"1111 (GCHelper) playerID: [%@]", [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID);

            // --
WebViewController *yourClassInstance = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

            [yourClassInstance Load_URL:true]; // this is not working as expected!!
            // -
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(error.localizedDescription);
        }

    })];

} else {
    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
}
}
```

**WebViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

-(void) Load_URL:(BOOL)Nativa;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *PagPrincipal;

@end
```

**WebViewController.m**

```
#import "WebViewController.h"
#import "NSData+AESCrypt.h"
#import "NSString+AESCrypt.h"
#import "NSString+URL_Encode.h"
#import "GCHelper.h"


@interface WebViewController ()

-(void) Load_URL:(BOOL)Nativa;

@end

-(void) Load_URL :(BOOL)Nativa
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.webgameurl.com"];

NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"iac=%@", [self URL_Codigo :Nativa :vip_aux]];

NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];


[requestObj setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];


[requestObj setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// HERE!! This returns null when called from GCHelper.m, but is ok when called from WebViewController.m !!
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Webview >>> >>> >>> [%@]", _PagPrincipal.description]);

_PagPrincipal.delegate = self;

    [_PagPrincipal loadRequest:requestObj];
```

This is it. The `_PagPrincipal` is the `UIWebView` itself, it's a storyboard. I'm not an iOS Objective-C specialist, so for sure there are things I just don't master. Using Xcode 6.1.1, the app is designed for iOS8+. Testing in a real iPad Mini 1 (non-retina) and iPhone 5.